# Why does my Firefox extension to add an upload-file button only work on one chat page?

Tags: javascript, json, artificial-intelligence, firefox-addon

I am trying to make an extension for FireFox/Gecko-based browsers that add an upload-file button to chat.openai.com. When I add my extension, it'll only add the button when I refresh on 1 chat page. If I go to a past chat, it won't put in the button. (BTW, I wrote this code with the help of ChatGPT lol).

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "ChatGPT File Upload",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Adds a button to upload files into ChatGPT. (NOT for images, videos, Word Documents, or other non-raw-text files. Please use .txt, .js, .py, .html, .css, .json, and .csv.",
    "permissions": [
      "scripting",
      "https://chat.openai.com/*"
    ],
    "action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "128": "icon128.png",
        "256": "icon128.png"
      }
    },
    "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.png",
      "256": "icon256.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://chat.openai.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
  }
```

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.url && changeInfo.url.startsWith('https://chat.openai.com/')) {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabId },
        files: ['content.js']
      });
    }
  });
```

content.js:

```
console.log("Content script loaded.");

// This script will be injected into chat.openai.com pages
// You can add your desired functionality here
// Create the button
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = ' Submit File';
button.style.backgroundColor = '#35393d';
button.style.color = 'white';
button.style.padding = '5px';
button.style.border = '1px solid #6b6458';
button.style.borderRadius = '5px';
button.style.margin = '5px';
button.style.width = '180px';

// Create a container div for centering
const containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
containerDiv.style.display = 'flex';
containerDiv.style.justifyContent = 'center';

// Append the button to the container div
containerDiv.appendChild(button);

// Find the target element
const targetElement = document.querySelector("div.relative.flex.h-full.max-w-full.flex-1.overflow-hidden > div > main > div.absolute.bottom-0 > form > div > div:nth-child(1)");

// Insert the container div before the target element
targetElement.parentNode.insertBefore(containerDiv, targetElement);

// Add click event listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  // Create the file input element
  const fileInput = document.createElement('input');
  fileInput.type = 'file';
  fileInput.accept = '.txt, .js, .py, .html, .css, .json, .csv';

  // Handle file selection
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = async (e) => {
        const fileContent = e.target.result;
        const chunkSize = 15000;
        const chunks = [];

        // Split file content into chunks
        for (let i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i += chunkSize) {
          const chunk = fileContent.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
          chunks.push(chunk);
        }

        // Submit each chunk to the conversation
        for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
          const chunk = chunks[i];
          const part = i + 1;
          const filename = file.name;
          await submitConversation(chunk, part, filename);
        }
      };

      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
  });

  // Trigger file input click event
  fileInput.click();
});

// Submit conversation function
async function submitConversation(text, part, filename) {
  const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea[tabindex='0']");
  const enterKeyEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    keyCode: 13,
  });
  textarea.value = `Part ${part} of ${filename}:\n\n${text}`;
  textarea.dispatchEvent(enterKeyEvent);
}
```

I gone through different background.js's that I found online, but none seemed to solve my issue. I'm very new to development, so I'm mostly lost on this sort of thing.

Comment: You have to listen for document changes and reinsert the button when there is a change in DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding my comment here.

There can be two types of navigations

1. Full page refresh
2. Javascript based page load

In the first case the extension will do its job and load the button but in the second case if the web app is loading the whole page with new elements then your "edited" element will get replaced with a new element.

You can solve this in two ways (AFAIK)

1. Listening to navigation changes
2. Mutation Observer

**Listening to navigation Event**

If the web app is changing the address in address bar then you can listen to that event and add the button if not already present.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/navigate_event

```js
navigation.addEventListener("navigate", (event) => {
  checkAndInjectButton()
})
```

**Mutation Observer**

If for some reason you are not able to detect navigation change in web app then you can listen to the changes in DOM and react based on the event.

Mutation oberver keeps track of attributes, child node and sub tree so if any changes are made to the target element, your script will get a callback.

```js
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetElement = document.querySelector("div.relative.flex.h-full.max-w-full.flex-1.overflow-hidden > div > main > div.absolute.bottom-0 > form > div > div:nth-child(1)");

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  checkAndInjectButton();
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetElement, config);

// If you need to stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Both the solutions will go to your `content.js`

Comment: Mutation Observer worked flawlessly! Thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

I will post a skeleton of the procedure using the method: "Listening to navigation changes". It is complex but i didn't find any easer solution. The code is a simplified part of an add-on for firefox which is working. The reason to make that add-on was to help users make fewer clicks in intranet pages (automation). You need "webRequest" under "permittions": [ ]. I use "manifest_version": 2

```
/* CONTENT SCRIPT anyname.js */
"use strict"
function listenAny(I, sender, outcom) {
   if (I.what == SID_REQ_COMPLETE) {
      
      //Here listen for messages from background.js  //from line with //@@1
      //the page maybe load something by ajax call
      DoAnythingInPage(2)  // 2 => reason is PAGE MODIFIED

   }
}
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(listenAny)

function start() {
   //send message to background and wait a response to take the information: 
   //in whitch tab this script is loaded (via Response.tabid)
   browser.runtime.sendMessage({ what: SID_LOADING }).then((Response) => {

      //here the script knows in whitch tab is executing  
      DoAnythingInPage(1)  // 1 => reason is PAGE LOADING
      
   }).catch((e) => {
      //
   })
}

function DoAnythingInPage(reason) {
   //HERE WRITE THE CODE TO MODIFY THE PAGE. THE reason MEANS
   // a)the page is loading of xmlhttprequest or b) some partial loading happans, maybe ajax request
   // You will deside what to do in any case
}


//when the page loads this is the first line of code to execute:
start()



/* BACKGROUND.JS*/
"use strict"
let tabsIwant = []
const urlFilter = {
   urls: ['https://chat.openai.com/*','https://anything.else.com/*']
}

function back_listenAny(rq, sender, resp) {
   if (rq.what == SID_LOADING) {
      //in an array store all tabs in whitch the content script loads
      tabsIwant.push(sender.tab.id)
      resp({ tabid: sender.tab.id }) 
   }
}

function removeTab(tabId) {
   let i = tabsIwant.indexOf(tabId)
   if (i >= 0) {
      tabsIwant.splice(i, 1)
   }
}

function onReqComplete(rDtls) {
   if (rDtls.fromCache || (rDtls.type != 'xmlhttprequest') || rDtls.tabId == -1 ) return  
   //in line above you can eliminate firing the SID_REQ_COMPLETE to content script 
   //after analysing the requests from browser tools. 
   //In my case I did the following additional checks
   /*|| rDtls.url.search('/images/') >= 0 || rDtls.url.search('/resources/') >= 0 */

   //check if this tab is in your interests... 
   //you don't need this check (and all the code that supports the array tabsIwant) if the urlFilter
   //contains only one domain
   if (tabsIwant.indexOf(rDtls.tabId) >= 0) {
      browser.tabs.sendMessage(rDtls.tabId, { what: SID_REQ_COMPLETE, rDtls: rDtls }) //@@1
         .catch((e) => {
            //...
         })
   }
}

browser.tabs.onRemoved.addListener((tabId, removeInfo) => {
   removeTab(tabId)
})

browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(onReqComplete, urlFilter)
```